# Configure GKE Load Balancer CDN with signed cookies

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-cdn

I have a Google Kubernetes cluster, and I would like to add a CDN with [signed cookies](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-cookies#examples). For that I have to do some load balancer configuration such as creating a [signed request key](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-cookies#creatingkeys)
and create a [policy](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-cookies#creating_a_policy).

How can I do this with the proper automation tools. I see these paths:

- GKE Ingress controller annotations (is there a big list of all available ones?) -- I haven't found the right annotations to implement cookies.
- Terraform seems to allow all such configuration, but Terraform cannot manage load balancer created by the GKE Ingress.
- Create a [standalone zonal network endpoint groups (NEGs)](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/standalone-neg#standalone_negs) configuration of of my GKE cluster, and manage LB with Terraform. This seems to be the most promising path, but also the most cumbersome and complex, so I was hoping to avoid it in favor of using Ingress annotations.

Comment: Hello, have you seen official documentation about GKE Ingress features: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features? Also the Ingress annotations can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features. As for the signed cookies you could follow this link: https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-cookies#creatingkeys

Comment: Dawid, you have the same link twice.  I have read all those pages in detail, but they don't answer my question -- how can I do the above with automation (i.e. purely inside k8s, or if not possible, in k8s + terraform)

Comment: Yes, my bad. The second link should be this one: [LINK](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/load-balance-ingress#summary_of_external_ingress_annotations). GKE `Ingress` doesn't have annotations for `cloudcdn` cookies (only `sessionAffinity`) I'm not sure why are trying to connect `Ingress` resource with signed-cookies as the documentation states that it's done/configured on the backend (application side). Please take a look on this example:  Configure `CloudCDN` with `BackendConfig`: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#expandable-1

Comment: There's apparently a bug in the docs. The Service annotation needs to be `beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default":"my-backendconfig"}'` and not the ports object they describe.